# iOS UIView animation move over another UIView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, move

Hi guys I have 2 UIViews. First UIView is moving via animation, but when it reaches second UIView it moving under it. How to move First UIView over the second UIView?

Here is my code (self.openView is first UIView, self.showView is second UIView):

```
- (void)cardImage:(NSString *)cardContent{
    self.cardOpenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",cardContent]]];
    self.cardOpenImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.openView.frame.size.width, self.openView.frame.size.height);
    UIImageView *cardBacksImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardbacks.png"]];
    cardBacksImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.openView.frame.size.width, self.openView.frame.size.height);
    [self.openView addSubview:cardBacksImage];
    [UIView transitionFromView:cardBacksImage
                        toView:self.cardOpenImage
                        duration:1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self moveToLeft:nil finished:nil context:nil];

                    }];
}
- (void)moveToLeft:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                         self.openView.center = CGPointMake(247, 180);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Move to left done");
                     }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.openView.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.openView];
```

Will bring `self.openView` to the top of it's superview's view hierarchy. This will work assuming both of your `UIViews` are subviews of the same superview.